# Ngram frequency ranking in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to read a fairly large document and extract N-grams(Continous sequence of N words) from it. I would also like to sort it in ascending order of frequency. While I understand this is an extension of word count, I am not sure how to do this in Pyspark. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution with [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz)

```
from toolz.curried import sliding_window
from operator import add, itemgetter

rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
tokens = rdd.map(str.split)

counts = (tokens
    .flatMap(sliding_window(3))
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(add))

counts.top(3, key=itemgetter(1))

## [(('command,', 'which', 'should'), 2),
## (('on', 'how', 'to'), 2),
## (('Please', 'refer', 'to'), 2)]
```

Limitation of this approach is pretty much the same as usual - it operates on line by line basis so if documents spans over multiple lines you won't get n-grams which spanned over line boundaries.

It is possible to correct for that by keeping track of line number and position in line or using `wholeTextFiles`.